# c++ general feedback on a custom performance oriented array

Tags: c++, design-patterns

**Introduction**
I have written a first iteration of a 3d rendering-program utilizing openGL and c++ and i am looking to get some of my code reviewed.
As i am self-taught and have never received any input on my coding i am looking forward to all sorts of feedback regarding style, abstraction, architecture, algorithm design or performance.

The code snippets showcased below are intended as an abstraction layer between the rest of the application and the openGL code. They manage the data for rendering-specific attributes of instances of the same mesh.
As these are intended to run in the main loop of later versions i had a concern for performance or at least tried to keep it scaleable for later optimizations. I also wanted to keep things as general as possible, so i don't have to repeat myself for different rendering cases.

The idea behind this is to provide a ready-to-use framework so i can render different concepts, such as mathematical functions with a minimal effort;
Or to serve as a basis for a 3d game engine.

**Questions**
Here are some specific Questions i have but feel free to point out other things that are good/bad.

Is the whole Concept something that could be done in a professional environment?
How far off is the class design from a best practice perspective?

Is it a good idea to omit polymorphism for performance?
As there are potentially a lot of these Containers i have tried to rely on function pointers to remove the overhead of hash-table-lookups.

How fleshed out should a Container-interface be?
Is it good practice to keep the classes rather slim and just add functionality as needed
or should I provide them with more methods to have a more complete interface to the rest of the application?

**The code and what it does**
There are 3 separate parts of the design included:

1. The "uniformContainer"
   This is a common interface providing every instance with an id, the possibility to sort by id and a hook into the GPU-specific code.
2. The "uniformContainer_list"
   This is the big container holding all existing instances of these containers. It is in turn held by another class utilizing templates to automate the execution of all "pipelines" in need of main-loop updates.

dynamicRenderData.h:

```
#ifndef DYNAMMICRENDERDATA_H
#define DYNAMMICRENDERDATA_H
#include <functional>
#include "utils.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "math/glm/vec3.hpp"
#include "math/glm/mat4x4.hpp"
#include "math/glm/ext/matrix_transform.hpp"
#include "math/glm/gtx/euler_angles.hpp"
#include "GPUbuffer.h"


//the pipeline class is just a dummy with a single virtual method

struct uniformContainer;
struct uniformContainer_list : public pipeline
{
    enum pipelinetrafos:int{
        sort=0,
        time_update=1
    };

    
    struct pipelineFuncPtrs
    {
        std::function<void()> sort;
        std::function<void()> internal;
        std::function<void(float)> dt;
        std::function<void()> GPU_upload;
    };

    std::function<void(const float)> getPipe()
    {return [this](const float dt){this->pipe(dt);};}
    
    void addContainer(const std::string name, uniformContainer* container);

    std::unordered_map<std::string, uniformContainer*> containers;
private:
    void unpackEntryTicket(pipelineFuncPtrs ticket);

    void onSort(){for(auto it: sort_stage)it();}
    void onDtUpdate(const float dt){for(auto it:dt_update_stage)it(dt);}
    void onInternalUpdate(){for(auto it: internal_update_stage)it();}
    void onGPUUpload(){for(auto it: on_GPU_upload_stage)it();}
    void pipe(const float dt)
    {
        this->onSort();
        this->onDtUpdate(dt);
        this->onInternalUpdate();
        this->onGPUUpload();
    }

    
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> sort_stage;
    std::vector<std::function<void(float)>> dt_update_stage;
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> internal_update_stage;
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> on_GPU_upload_stage;
};
template<typename T>
T* allocateAndCopy(const size_t newSize, T* oldData, const int dataIndex)
{
    T* newArray=new T[newSize+newSize%8];
    memcpy(newArray, oldData, dataIndex*sizeof(T));
    delete[] oldData;
    return newArray;
}


struct uniformContainer{
protected:
    uniformContainer( const size_t isize, const int iuID);
    //RULE OF 5
    uniformContainer(const uniformContainer& from);
    uniformContainer& operator=(const uniformContainer& from);
    uniformContainer(uniformContainer&& from)noexcept;
    uniformContainer& operator=(uniformContainer&& from)noexcept;
    ~uniformContainer()
    {
        delete[] entityIDs;
    }
    

    
        
    int add();

    //removes the ID from the container.
    //actual removal is not happening until the next sort
    void remove(const int ID);
    void reAllocate(const size_t newSize);
    void sortWithData(std::function<void(int, int*)> subSorts); 
    void onBulkRemoval();
    

    int IDCounter=0;
    int* entityIDs;
    int writeIndex=0;
    std::vector<subBufferHandle> myGPUBuffer;
private:
    std::vector<int> deleteQue;
    int typeID=-1;
    size_t entitySize;
    
public:
    struct iterator{
        iterator(const int iindex, uniformContainer* imyCont)
        :index(iindex), myCont(imyCont){}
        
        iterator& operator++(){++index;return *this;}
        iterator& operator--(){--index;return *this;}
        bool operator==(const uniformContainer::iterator& rhs)
        {return this->index==rhs.index;}
        iterator& operator=(const iterator& rhs)=default;
        int operator*(){return *((myCont->entityIDs)+index);}

        int index;
        uniformContainer* myCont;
    };
    iterator begin(){return iterator(0, this);}
    int getTypeID()const{return this->typeID;}
    int end()const{return writeIndex;}
    size_t size()const{return entitySize;}


    //virutal pipeline entrytickets
    virtual uniformContainer_list::pipelineFuncPtrs makeEntryTicket()=0;


    //el printore
    void printIDs(const char* msg="")const;
};



#endif //DYNAMMICRENDERDATA_H
```

dynamicRenderData.cpp:

```cpp
#include "dynamicRenderData.h"
#include <string.h>

void uniformContainer_list::addContainer(
    const std::string name,
    uniformContainer* container
)
{
    this->containers.insert({name, container});
    this->unpackEntryTicket(container->makeEntryTicket());
}

void uniformContainer_list::unpackEntryTicket(pipelineFuncPtrs ticket)
{
    if(ticket.sort)
    {
        sort_stage.push_back(ticket.sort);
    }
    if(ticket.dt)
    {
        dt_update_stage.push_back(ticket.dt);
    }
    if(ticket.internal)
    {
        internal_update_stage.push_back(ticket.internal);
    }
    if(ticket.GPU_upload)
    {
        on_GPU_upload_stage.push_back(ticket.GPU_upload);
    }

}



uniformContainer::uniformContainer( const size_t isize, const int iuID)
:typeID(iuID), entitySize(isize+isize%8),  
entityIDs(new int[isize+isize%8]())
{
    for(size_t i=0;i<entitySize;++i)
    {
        entityIDs[i]=-1;
    }
}
//RULE OF 5
uniformContainer::uniformContainer(const uniformContainer& from)
:IDCounter(from.IDCounter), writeIndex(from.writeIndex), entitySize(from.entitySize),
deleteQue(from.deleteQue), typeID(from.typeID)
{
    entityIDs=new int[entitySize];
    memset(entityIDs, -1, entitySize*sizeof(int));
    memcpy(entityIDs, from.entityIDs, writeIndex*sizeof(int));
}
uniformContainer& uniformContainer::operator=(const uniformContainer& from)
{
    if(this==&from) return *this;
    if(from.writeIndex!=this->entitySize)
    {
        this->reAllocate(from.entitySize);
    }
    
    this->IDCounter=from.IDCounter;
    this->entitySize=from.entitySize;
    this->writeIndex=from.writeIndex;
    this->deleteQue=from.deleteQue;
    this->typeID=from.typeID;
    memcpy(this->entityIDs, from.entityIDs, this->entitySize);
    return *this;
}
uniformContainer::uniformContainer(uniformContainer&& from)noexcept
:IDCounter(from.IDCounter), writeIndex(from.writeIndex), entitySize(from.entitySize),
deleteQue(from.deleteQue), typeID(from.typeID)
{
    this->entityIDs=from.entityIDs;
    from.entityIDs=nullptr;
    from.entitySize=0;
}
uniformContainer& uniformContainer::operator=(uniformContainer&& from)noexcept
{
    if(this->entityIDs)delete[] this->entityIDs;
    this->IDCounter=from.IDCounter;
    this->entitySize=from.entitySize;
    this->writeIndex=from.writeIndex;
    this->deleteQue=std::move(from.deleteQue);
    this->typeID=from.typeID;
    
    from.entityIDs=nullptr;
    from.entitySize=0;
    return *this;
}





int uniformContainer::add()
{
    if(writeIndex==entitySize-1)
    {
        DEBUGMSG("\n uniform container full!");
        return -1;
    }
    return (entityIDs[writeIndex++]=IDCounter++);        
}
void uniformContainer::remove(const int ID)
{
    if(ID==-1)return;
    this->deleteQue.push_back(ID);
    
}

void uniformContainer::reAllocate(const size_t newSize)
{
    int* newArray=new int[newSize+newSize%8];
    memset(newArray, -1, entitySize*sizeof(int));
    memcpy(newArray, entityIDs, writeIndex*sizeof(int));
    delete[] entityIDs;
    entityIDs=allocateAndCopy(newSize, entityIDs, writeIndex);
    entitySize=newSize;
}


void uniformContainer::onBulkRemoval()
{
    for(int& id : deleteQue)
    {
        int end=writeIndex-1, mid=writeIndex-1/2;
        while(id!=entityIDs[mid]&&end!=mid)
        {
            if(id<entityIDs[mid])
            {
                end=entityIDs[mid];
                entityIDs[mid]/=2;
            }
            else if(id>entityIDs[mid])
            {
                entityIDs[mid]+=(end-entityIDs[mid])/2;
            }
        }
        if(id!=entityIDs[mid])
        {
            id=writeIndex;
        }
        else{
            id=mid;
        }
    }
    for(int id:deleteQue)
    {
        entityIDs[id]=-1;
    }
    deleteQue.clear();
}

void uniformContainer::sortWithData(std::function<void(int, int*)> subSorts)
{
    if(deleteQue.empty())
    {
        return;
    }
    
    onBulkRemoval();

    int i=0, k=0, j;
    //this was written with SIMD intrinsics in mind, thats why its 8
    int gather[8];
    int value[8];
    int gatherIndex=0;
    //__m256i intv8;
    while(k<writeIndex-8)
    {
        for(gatherIndex=0;gatherIndex<8;++k)
        {
            if(entityIDs[k]!=-1)
            {
                gather[gatherIndex++]=k;
            }
            
        }
        
        
        
        for(j=0;j<8;++j)
        {
            value[j]=entityIDs[gather[j]];
        }
        for(j=0;j<8;++j)
        {
            entityIDs[i+j]=value[j];
        }
        
        
       
        subSorts(i, gather);
        
        
        i+=8;
    }
    //look at the last 8
    for(j=0;j<8;++j)
    {
        gather[j]=writeIndex;
    }
    for(gatherIndex=0;k<writeIndex;++k)
    {
        if(entityIDs[k]!=-1)
        {
            gather[gatherIndex++]=k;
        }
    }
    for(j=0;j<8;++j)
    {
        value[j]=entityIDs[gather[j]];
    }
    for(j=0;j<8;++j)
    {
        entityIDs[i+j]=value[j];
    }
    subSorts(i, gather);

    //set write index
    writeIndex=i+gatherIndex;
    //printf("\n sort done");
}
```

3. An implementation of a "Uniform container"
   managing the associated data for an object.
   (I know the destructor is missing and I am working on it)

```cpp
enum uniformID : int{
    _uniform3d,
    gridUniform
};

struct oneUniform3d{
    oneUniform3d(const glm::vec3 t, const glm::vec3 r, const glm::vec3 s)
    :trans(t), rot(r), scale(s)
    {}
    glm::vec3 trans;
    glm::vec3 rot;
    glm::vec3 scale;
};
struct uniform3d : public uniformContainer
{
    static const uniformID myID=uniformID::_uniform3d;

    uniform3d(const size_t isize, std::string name)
    :uniformContainer(isize, myID),trans(new glm::vec3[isize+isize%8]),rot(new glm::vec3[isize+isize%8]()), scale(new glm::vec3[isize+isize%8]),
    model(new glm::mat4[isize+isize%8])
    {

        if(!trans||!scale||!rot||!model)
        {
            throw bad_construction_exe(bad_construction_exe::bad_alloc,
            "uniform3d allocation failed with size: "+std::to_string(isize));
        }
        subBufferHandle sbh=masterContainer::_GPUBuffers.dynamic_draw.newSubBuffer(isize*16);
        if(!sbh.buffer)
        {
            throw bad_construction_exe(
                bad_construction_exe::bad_gpu_subBufferHandle,
                "newSubBUffer on dynamic_draw returned null, on uniform3d construction with size:"+std::to_string(isize));
        }
        this->myGPUBuffer.push_back(sbh);
        this->myGPUBuffer[0].buffer->init_subBuffer(this->myGPUBuffer[0].subBufferID,
        16, 0);
        masterContainer::subBuffers.insert({name+"_model", myGPUBuffer[0]});
    }

    void remove(const int ID)
    {
        uniformContainer::remove(ID);
    }
    
    //TODO() realloc function if we get too big
    //TODO() update method

    void reAllocate(const size_t newSize)
    {
        if(newSize<writeIndex)
        {
            DEBUGMSG("\n unfiromContainer reAlloc failed: trying to shrink w    writeIndex");
            return;
        }
        trans=allocateAndCopy(newSize, trans, writeIndex);
        rot=allocateAndCopy(newSize, rot, writeIndex);
        scale=allocateAndCopy(newSize, scale, writeIndex);

    }

    int add()
    {
        int id=uniformContainer::add();
        if(id==-1)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        trans[writeIndex-1]=glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
        rot[writeIndex-1]=glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
        scale[writeIndex-1]=glm::vec3(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
        return id;
    }
    int add(const glm::vec3 itrans, const glm::vec3 irot, const glm::vec3    iscale)
    {
        int id=uniformContainer::add();
        if(id==-1)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        trans[writeIndex-1]=itrans;
        rot[writeIndex-1]=irot;
        scale[writeIndex-1]=iscale;
        return id;
    }
    std::vector<int> addN(
        const std::vector<glm::vec3> itrans, 
        const std::vector<glm::vec3> iscale, 
        const std::vector<glm::vec3> irot
    )
    {
        std::vector<int> ret;
        int curr, i;
        for(i=0;i<itrans.size(); ++i)
        {
            if((curr=uniformContainer::add())==-1)
            {
                DEBUGMSG("\n uniformcontainer full! addN aborted!");
                break;
            }
            ret.push_back(curr);
            trans[writeIndex-1]=itrans[i];
            scale[writeIndex-1]=iscale[i];
            rot[writeIndex-1]=irot[i];
        }
        return ret;
    }
    std::vector<int> addN(const std::vector<oneUniform3d> entity)
    {
        std::vector<int> ret;
        int curr, i;
        for(i=0;i<entity.size(); ++i)
        {
            if((curr=uniformContainer::add())==-1)
            {
                DEBUGMSG("\n uniformcontainer full! addN aborted!");
                break;
            }
            ret.push_back(curr);
            trans[writeIndex-1]=entity[i].trans;
            scale[writeIndex-1]=entity[i].scale;
            rot[writeIndex-1]=entity[i].rot;
        }
        return ret;
    }
    void sort()
    {
        auto nestedSort=[](int i, int* gather, glm::vec3* data)
        {   
            glm::vec3 temp[8];
            for(char k=0;k<8;k++)
            {
                temp[k]=data[gather[k]];
            }
            memcpy(data+i, temp, 8*sizeof(glm::vec3));
        };
        auto sortLmbd=[nestedSort, this](int i, int* gather){
            nestedSort(i, gather, trans);
            nestedSort(i, gather, rot);
            nestedSort(i, gather, scale);
        };
        sortWithData(sortLmbd);
    }
    void buildModelMats()
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<writeIndex;++i)
        {
            model[i]=glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), scale[i]);

        }
        for(i=0;i<writeIndex;++i)
        {
            model[i]=glm::eulerAngleXYZ(rot[i].x,rot[i].y,rot[i].z)*model[i];

        }
        for(i=0;i<writeIndex;++i)
        {
            model[i]=glm::translate(model[i], trans[i]);
            //printf("\n printing mat %i", i);
            //printmat4(model[i]);
        }
    }

    void internalUpdate()
    {
        this->buildModelMats();
    }

    void onUpload()
    {
        this->myGPUBuffer[0].buffer->writeToSubBuffer(
            this->myGPUBuffer[0].subBufferID,
             this->writeIndex*16,
              (float*)model);
    }

    std::vector<oneVertexArraySetup> getVAOstats(std::string name)const
    {
        std::vector<oneVertexArraySetup> ret=
        {
            oneVertexArraySetup(masterContainer::subBuffers.at(name+"_model"), 1, 2)
        };
        return ret;
    }
    
    uniformContainer_list::pipelineFuncPtrs makeEntryTicket()
    {
        uniformContainer_list::pipelineFuncPtrs p;
        p.sort=std::bind(&uniform3d::sort, std::ref(*this));
        p.dt=nullptr;
        p.internal=std::bind(&uniform3d::buildModelMats, std::ref(*this));
        p.GPU_upload=std::bind(&uniform3d::onUpload, std::ref(*this));
        return p;
    }

    //build matrix or leave raw?
    glm::vec3* trans;
    glm::vec3* rot;
    glm::vec3* scale;

    glm::mat4* model;
};
```

If you wish to see more context to the above examples, please let me know. I am would be happy to provide a follow-up question or post a link to the github repository.

**EDIT:**
Link to the repo:
https://github.com/iamveryseriousandgoodcodewriter/3dwave

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. Our primary goal on this site is helping you improve your coding ability by making insightful observations about the code. We may or may not discuss the software design during the code review. I suggest you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). It would be very helpful if you added a link to the repository. It would also be helpful if the implementation of the `Uniform container` included the header files.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I didn't find them and was not sure how much code to actually post. The implementation is a header-only file and it's include doesn't make sense without the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2):

## Answers to your questions

> Is the whole Concept something that could be done in a professional environment?

The concept is certainly something that could be done professionally. There are many commercial 3D engines out there.

> How far off is the class design from a best practice perspective?

It's quite far off unfortunately. See below for some of the issues I see with this code.

> Is it a good idea to omit polymorphism for performance? As there are potentially a lot of these Containers i have tried to rely on function pointers to remove the overhead of hash-table-lookups.

It depends. If you need to decide at runtime what function to call, there might be several options, including dynamic polymorphism, and they will all have some overhead.

However, if you can avoid *runtime* polymorphism and just use *static* polymorphism, that would be better. Also consider templates; just like the STL containers being templated on the type of data they contain, you could make your `uniformContainer` a template for the type of uniforms they store.

> How fleshed out should a Container-interface be? Is it good practice to keep the classes rather slim and just add functionality as needed or should I provide them with more methods to have a more complete interface to the rest of the application?

It depends on the use case. If this is just going to be used in one of your own projects, then I would recommend following the [YAGNI principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it), and only implement what you need. However, if this is intended to be used by others, then you should have a complete interface for it to be as useful for others as possible. But unless you already know up front what that "complete interface" should be and have some users, then I would first spend time on other things.

## Code style

Your code style is very inconsistent, some times you have no spaces around things, sometimes you do. Some functions are written on a single line, others use multiple lines even if there is only one statement in the body.

It doesn't really matter what style you adopt, as long as you are consistent. Also, don't waste time manually reformatting your code; use a code formatting tool like [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) or [ClangFormat](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) to reformat your code automatically.

## Avoid manual memory management

I see lots of `new` and `delete` in your code. I strongly recommend that you avoid manual memory management where possible. Instead, use containers like `std::vector`, or smart pointers like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) that will automatically free things for you. You already use `std::vector` in lots of places, I don't see why you didn't use it for `entityIDs` as well.

Also note that `new` normally never returns `nullptr`; if it fails it will throw a [`std::bad_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) exception. The same goes for the STL containers; if they cannot allocate any more memory, they will throw that exception as well.

## Prefer C++ library functions over C ones

Instead of using `memcpy()`, use [`std::copy_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) to copy parts of one array to another. There are a lot of [C++ algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) that can do most things for you without having to resort to C functions, and they have the added benefit of being type safe.

## Unnecessary use of `this->`

You almost never have to write `this->` in C++. Just omit it.

## Use `override` and `final` where appropriate

If you are using virtual functions in base classes, make sure you use the `override` keyword when overriding those functions in the derived classes. The compiler will then check that you are actually overriding an existing virtual function. It also makes it easier for someone else reading your code, they can see which functions in the derived class are actually part of the virtual interface.

Use `final` for functions that should never be overriden. That can be used both in the base class and in the derived class.

## Naming things

I don't think the names you gave to classes and functions are very clear. The most egregious example is `uniform3d`; if you just see that name you wouldn't expect it to be a container. You also ahd to name the actual type describing a single uniform "`oneUniform3d`".

`uniformContainer_list` is also weird, not only because it mixes camelCase and snake_case. Apart from not even being a list but a `std::unordered_map` internally, it's also a `pipeline`?

Some things are abbreviated unnecessarily or in a weird way. I assume `onDtUpdate()` is called for every time step, but it's not updating the size of a time step. Perhaps `onTimeStep()` would be a better name, or `onAdvanceTime()`. Also, `pipe()` is not even a verb. Perhaps `executePipeline()` would be better? And `deleteQue` should be `deleteQueue` or `deletedIDs`.

## Returning lambdas unnecessarily?

I don't see why `getPipe()` returns a lambda, which in turn just calls `this->pipe()`. Why not make `pipe()` public? If the caller needs to store it in a `std::function` it can do so itself.

## Reduce the responsibilities of each class

Your classes just do too many things at the same time. For example, `uniform3d` is a container for multiple `oneUniform3d`s, but apart form just managing that container, it is splitting `oneUniform3d`s into 3 separate arrays of `glm::vec3`s, it is also deriving a model matrix from translation, rotation and scale vectors, and handling uploads to GPU buffers.

I would say, follow the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID), but it's hard to explain them in a few sentences. Spend some time looking for books or online resources like tutorial videos explaining the concepts. I also wish I could just show you how to restructure your classes, but without the full code it's hard for me to see what the best way to structure them is.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. I have edited in a link to the repository for the whole project. It would be great if you could provide me with some examples on how to properly restructure the classes. On a side note: I can't yet upvote your comment, there is a techincal problem with my account signup